# SQL month to day average (auto)

Tags: sql-server-2014

How to count the day for average use in SQL?

for example, I can use today()-20171001 to count it is 22 for average use in excel which it is automatic.

I need count the average value of the computer in Oct-2017 to day.

table: computer data

```
date       |    property   |    computer code | value
----------      --------        -----------    -------
20160131   |   companyA   |     256584        | 1,000
20160131   |   companyB   |     987451        | 1,200
...
20171022   |   companyA   |     157489        | 1,600
20171022   |   companyA   |     589741        | 1,400
20171022   |   comapnyA   |     547182        | 2,750
```

sql:

```
select property
,sum (case when  property = 'companyA' then value end) / ( the code I have asked - the answer should be 22, 20171023-20171001) as avgvalue_computer

from computer table

group by property
order by property
```

---

the result I wanted

```
property | avgvalue_computer
companyA | 8,500         <- 2017-Oct-01 to 2017-Oct-23 (today)
companyB | 16,800        <- 2017-Oct-01 to 2017-Oct-23 (today)
```

Comment: Maybe datediff(day, '20171001', getdate())? Or maybe just avg(value)? Avg will also take care of missing dates. If there's more then one record per day, then you'll need more logic

Comment: datediff(day, '20171001', getdate())  is very useful!!! thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE (Date DATE, Property VARCHAR(20), PropertyCode INT, [Value] FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('20161031','cA', 256584, 1000)
SELECT Property CompanyName, MTD.Value, MTD.DateFrom, MTD.DateTo
FROM @Table T1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT AVG(VALUE) Value, DATEADD (D,
                                DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) *-1, 
                                 GETDATE()) DateFrom, GETDATE() DateTo
           FROM @Table T2
           WHERE T2.PropertyCode = T1.PropertyCode
           AND T2.Date BETWEEN (DATEADD (D,
                                DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) *-1, 
                                 GETDATE())) 
                    AND     GETDATE()
       ) MTD
```

Answer (score 0):

select property
,sum (case when  property = 'companyA' then value end) / datediff(day, '20171001', getdate())) as avgvalue_computer

from computer table

group by property
order by property